# Geometric Distribution - transformation $Y=x/(x+1)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I honestly have no idea where to start with this problem:

Suppose $X$ has the geometric distribution with PMF

$$f(x) = \frac 1 3 \left( \frac 2 3 \right)^x, x=1,2,.....$$

Determine the probability distribution of $Y=x/(x+1).$  Note that both $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables. To specify the probability distribution of $Y,$ specify its PMF.

Comment: You should have $Y=X/(X+1)$ rather than $Y=x/(x+1). \qquad $

Comment: I mentioned this in response to your comment on my answer, but I think you *do* mean to have $x = 0, 1, 2, \dots$ instead of $x = 1, 2, \dots$. Note that the probability function in your edit does not have total probability of $1$, which it needs to: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+%281%2F3%29%282%2F3%29%5Ex+from+x%3D+1+to+infinity

Answer (score 0):

To specify a variable's PMF, you need two things: (a) a list of what values it can be, and a corresponding list of probabilities of it being those values.

You already have the PMF for $X$, but let's make a table out of it to make it a bit more concrete.
$$\begin{array}{r | l}
  x & p(x) \\ \hline
  0 & 1/3 \\
  1 & \frac 1 3 \cdot \frac 2 3 = \frac 2 9 \\
  2 & \frac 1 3 \cdot (\frac 2 3)^2 = \frac 4 {27} \\
  \vdots & \vdots
\end{array}$$

I obtained the probabilities, denote above as $p(x)$, by plugging each value of $x$ into the given PMF.

Once you have these, you now have a complete listing of what $Y$ can be, along with all *its* probabilities. For instance, if $X = 0$, then $Y = \frac{X}{X+1} = \frac{0}{1} = 0$ as well; this will occur with probability $1/3$. If $X = 1$, then $Y = \frac{1}{2}$, which will occur with probability $2/9$, and so forth. Using this idea, you could make a table that looks just like the above, to get the the PMF for $Y$.

Of course, it may be more desirable to put this into a formula; you may want something compact like the expression you gave for $f(x)$. I claim that the clearest way to see what such a formula should be is to write out the first 3 or 4 lines of a table like the above, though.

Comment: I added values for x to clarify the question.

Comment: The condition you inserted makes the resulting function not a valid PMF since the total probability isn't $1$. (If $x = 0$ is possible, though, the PMF works fine.)